# Why is my video carousel stacking videos instead of showing them in slideshow?

Tags: html, video, carousel, slideshow

I'm trying to add a video carousel to my website and it keeps stacking videos on top of each other vertically instead of presenting them in a carousel slideshow. I also can't see the indicators to point to the next slide. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

```
<!--Carousel Wrapper-->
<div id="video-carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <!--Indicators-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#video-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#video-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#video-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--/.Indicators-->
    <!--Slides-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <video class="video-fluid" autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/Tropical.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video class="video-fluid" autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/forest.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video class="video-fluid" autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/Agua-natural.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.Slides-->
    <!--Controls-->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#video-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#video-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    <!--/.Controls-->
  </div>
  <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
```

Answer (score 0):

try it with the controls attribute.

```
<video class="video-fluid" controls autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/Agua-natural.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```